# how to populate cvc-complex-type error information in mule

Tags: validation, mule

I have mule message filters to validate SOAP Request against schema,

my question is:

how to log error details of 'which element is have parse exception (cvc-complex-type). because catch block is always trowing exception details: "Message has been rejected by filter". how can i show exact exception?. so that user will enter correct data on request.

Answer (score 0):

write a customfilterclass as a child of SchemaValidationfilter.

override accept method and throw soap fault.

```
public class CustomSchemaValidationFilter extends SchemaValidationFilter {
@Override
public boolean accept(MuleMessage muleMessage) {
    return validateBody(muleMessage);
}
public boolean validateBody(MuleMessage message) throws Fault {
    Source source = null;
    try {
        source = loadSource(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw getFaultObj(e);
    }
    try {
        createValidator().validate(source);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw getFaultObj(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw getFaultObj(e);
    }
    return true;
}
private Fault getFaultObj(Exception e) {
    return new SoapFault(e.getMessage(), e, new QName(
            DEFAULT_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE));
}
}
```

//and add in mule flow following tags to validate filter.

```
<custom-filter class="org.mule.module.xml.filters.CustomSchemaValidationFilter">
<spring:property name="schemaLocations" value="${approvalHistorySchemaLocation}" />
</custom-filter>**
```